# Mysql insert fixed column value for each row during multi-insert

Tags: mysql

In mysql when I'm doing

```
# fr-FR.sql
INSERT INTO table (resource_key, resource_value, locale) VALUES 
    ("GEN.YES", "Oui", "fr-FR"),
    ("GEN.NO", "Non", "fr-FR"),
    ("GEN.MAYBE", "Peut-être", "fr-FR")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `resource_value` = VALUES(`resource_value`);

# en-US.sql
INSERT INTO table (resource_key, resource_value, locale) VALUES 
    ("GEN.YES", "Yes", "en-US"),
    ("GEN.NO", "No", "en-US"),
    ("GEN.MAYBE", "Maybe", "en-US")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `resource_value` = VALUES(`resource_value`);
```

Here, 'resource_key' and 'locale' are the primary key. 'locale' is always the same in one file. But differ from file to file (can't set as default value);

This query works. It insert each row and if a label for a given resource_key/locale pair exists, it will update its associated resource_value

Is it possible to insert same value in each row for a given column. There is thousands of lines in different files (added continuously) and always typing the same string in each row is annoying.

Comment: Have you considered using a variable (which would still have to be inserted for each row), or setting a default for the column at the table level (which would then hold true until/unless the table definition was altered)? I assume these would fail to meet your need (for the reasons I've stated), but it never hurts to check.

Comment: I see 6 "random_str".  Are you saying that pairs are actually equal?  Or one column has all the same random string?  Please clarify, preferably by changing the 'example'.

Comment: Same problem with variables. Can't set default (see edited question). Pairs aren't equals; I updated my question so it's much more clear I think.

Comment: Nobody has any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surely too late for you, but maybe somebody will have similar question in the future.

A way how to accomplish that is by creating temporary table #temptable, and while copying data to actual table, add constant column:

```
# en-US.sql
INSERT INTO #temptable (resource_key, resource_value) VALUES 
    ("GEN.YES", "Yes"),
    ("GEN.NO", "No"),
    ("GEN.MAYBE", "Maybe")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `resource_value` = VALUES(`resource_value`);

INSERT INTO table (resource_key, resource_value, locale) VALUES 
    (SELECT t.*, "en-US" FROM #temptable AS t);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for creating an account just to answer me ! Really appreciate it. You're not too late, i just ignored that until now but i'll update it now I have a better solution. Thanks a lot !